# "z-index" like method across Browser Window / View

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

Apologies if this is answered somewhere else. will gladly take a link to a question like this that is already answered.
Thank you in advance for any responses and suggestions to the question

Short version: does there exist a way for content (like an image) to seamlessly pass across from Browser Window to a Browser View in Electron? somewhat in the sense of setting a z-index like property that keeps it on top of both browser view and browser window but still contained within the bounds of the browser window

Long version:
**before you mention it, this is attempting to not use a webview tag unless there is no other way as browser view seems to be the trend for stability

i currently have an electron app that is intended to be a single window instance. within that window there will be a section that contains 3rd party embedded content. right now im using a webview tag to embed said content and have an image that floats around on top of both the rootWindow html and the embeded content (since its part of the html).

if i swap to browser view which is said to be more stable, the root window html will get covered by the browser view as its not part of the root window html so  it can be said that the root window does not even know it exists as far as the renderer process is concerned.

however i need a small image to be able to stay on top of of both sections of the UI much in the same way that with a webview tag, i could have an image have an extremely high z-index and force it to stay on top of everything.

does there exist a way to have an image pass across both sections of the UI and stay at the very front of anything being rendered behind it?

a link to a visual representation (i cannot post it as part of the question as the site wont let me) is located here: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/280536739771056129/536009618703253515/Untitled.png; where the white space is representative of a Browser View bound, the blue space being the Browser Window containing the view, and the black square being the image or content that i need to move across both sections and have it show up on top of both

again, appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike WebView, BrowserView's implementation creates separates surface bounds and overlay on top of parent browserwindow, so any underlying element cannot be placed higher than activated browserview (z-index like approach).

In short, you can't do it with browserview unfortunately as it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

With multiple `BrowserView` support in newer Electron versions you can achieve your goal by adding the small image as last `BrowserView` (the last will be always the topmost).